# Is QNX channel is true bidirectional?

Tags: c++, qnx

I write C++ app on QNX neutrino with channels (`ChannelCreate` in parent/`ChannelAttach` in child process).

I dont undestand - these channels is fully bidirectional? Can I call `MsgSend` in parent and `MsgReceive`/`MsgReply` in child, like tcp socket? Or I cant do this and must call `MsgSend` only in child and `MsgReceive` in parent?

In [guide](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/qnxcar2/topic/com.qnx.doc.neutrino.sys_arch/topic/ipc_Channels.html) says that I can do it in one direction, but nothing about back direction.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its seems that qnx channel is not fully bidirectional. When I change my app to one-directional style, all starts working fine